# Updating entity using Entity Framework 4.1

Tags: entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I am trying to update an entity using Entity Framework 4.1 Code first approach. I am using following code:

```
public void UpdatePersonEmail(long registryID, string Email) {
            var Person = context.Persons.FirstOrDefault(p => p.RegistryID == registryID);
          //  Person = person;
            Person.Email = Email;
            try
            {
                context.Persons.Attach(Person);
                context.Entry(Person).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
            {
                foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Code is not giving any error but entity is not updated. I just want to update the email address.

Please suggest me solution.

Comment: Try running a sql trace against the DB to see what sql is actually sent.  Also, you don't really need to attach it to the context, since you already have a Person object from the context.  EF will figure out what has changed.

Comment: I see there no error with `context.SaveChanges();` sould every change be saved. Try to remove the line `context.Entry(Person).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;`. I see no sense for this line.

Comment: @rekire I removed it but still it is not working

Comment: I would say remove both the `context.Persons.Attach(Person);` and `context.Entry(Person).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;` lines.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you do FirstOrDefault, you should check to make sure the entity is not null. Try this:

```
public void UpdatePersonEmail(long registryID, string Email) 
{
    var person = context.Persons.FirstOrDefault(p => p.RegistryID == registryID);
    try
    {
        person.Email = Email;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
    {
        foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
        {
            foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
            {
                Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}", 
                    validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException nrEx)
    {
        Trace.TraceInformation("person was null.");
    }
}
```